# Grep and sed returning only first match

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am trying to extract the title and description of a rss Feed , I have written following script to return all the title in the Feed , But its returning only the first Title from the xml:

```
curl "http://www.dailystar.com.lb/RSS.aspx?id=113" 2>/dev/null  | grep -E -o "<title>(.*)</title>" |sed -e 's,.*<title>\(.*\)</title>.*,\1,g' | less
```

How can I also find the description ?

Comment: Without `2>/dev/null`, the curl output prints something like following at the beginning:

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  7248    0  7248    0     0  20011      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 36979

Comment: post the above comment in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep -P`:

```
curl "http://www.dailystar.com.lb/RSS.aspx?id=113" 2>/dev/null |\
      grep -oP "<title>\K[\s\S]*?(?=</title>)"
```

Comment: Yes the updated version gets data with newlines also.

Comment: Your original post did also work with new line, at least in my test.

Comment: This works , but how can i get the description of that title too?

Comment: @Nusrat provide the neccesary datas to figure it out.

Comment: @Nusrat Not sure what you mean by description of title? Can you provide an example.

Comment: The Feed has something like :
`<item>
<title>Hi</title>
<description>Saying Hi</description>
<link>some link</link>
</item>`
I want all the titles and descriptions : The print should display 
Hi 
Saying Hi 
............

Comment: For `<description>` tag use: `grep -oP "<description>\K[\s\S]*?(?=</description>)"`

Comment: I know it will give the description field , but how to get both of them together ? Because If I only add this line at the end the grep is executed after pipe lined , so nothing is printed :

`curl "http://www.dailystar.com.lb/RSS.aspx?id=113" 2>/dev/null |
      grep -oP "<title>\K[\s\S]*?(?=</title>)" | 
      grep -oP "<description>\K[\s\S]*?(?=</description>)"
`

Comment: No you cannot pipe both grep commands together. Store curl's output in a file first using `curl "http://www.dailystar.com.lb/RSS.aspx?id=113" 2>/dev/null > curl.out` then use grep commands **one be one** on `curl.out` file.

Comment: Also just to let you know your original problem was getting `<title>` tag only which I believe my answer solved it. Add new questions from comments section is not usually encouraged on SO.

Comment: I think you missed this part of my question :
How can I also find the description ?
Anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

First put each title and description on its own line. Here is an example:

```
curl "http://www.dailystar.com.lb/RSS.aspx?id=113" 2>/dev/null  | \
      grep -E -o "<title>(.*)</title>" | \
      sed -e 's,<\(title\|description\)>,\n<\1>,g' | 
      sed -n 's,.*<title>\(.*\)</title>.*,\1,gp'
```

For the description:

```
curl "http://www.dailystar.com.lb/RSS.aspx?id=113" 2>/dev/null  | \
      grep -E -o "<title>(.*)</title>" | \
      sed -e 's,<\(title\|description\)>,\n<\1>,g' | \
      sed 's,<title>\([^<]*\)</title>,T:\1,' | \
      sed 's,<description>\([^<]*\)</description>,D:\1,' | \
      sed -n 's/[DT]://p'
```

Comment: Hi, How to extract the description field too , I mean print both the title and descrition

Comment: Not working the second command , gives other field too, like <link> etc

Answer (score 0):

You should use non-greedy match (`.*?`) instead of greedy matching (`.*`) to get all the titles:

```
curl "http://www.dailystar.com.lb/RSS.aspx?id=113" 2>/dev/null  | grep -E -o "<title>(.*?)</title>" |sed -e 's,.*<title>\(.*?\)</title>.*,\1,g' | less
```

Comment: But its returning the whole xml , not only the titles!